# How to make application toolbar show an icon only?

Tags: menu

By default Ubuntu displays toolbar icons alongside its text. I want to make every applications toolbar to show icon only. I tried changing this value
`/desktop/gnome/interface/toolbar_style`
to `icons` using `gconf-editor` like mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/157101/change-toolbar-icon-settings-in-gnome-on-ubuntu-10-04-lts) and restart Ubuntu, but it didn't work.

Comment: which toolbars are you talking about?

Comment: every application toolbar

Answer (score 0):

Finally found it. 
Use `dconf-editor`. Tree path :`org/gnome/desktop/interface/toolbar-style`